# Even function that is injective

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

I have heard/read multiple times that an even function can't be injective. And the proof I see for this is the following:

An even function can never be injective because for every $x\neq 0$ we have $x\neq -x$ and $f(x)=f(-x)$

But what about the function:

$f(x)=\sqrt{-|x|}+73$

$f$ is defined in $A_f=\{0\}$

For every $x$ and $-x$ in the domain of $f$, the equation $f(x)=f(-x)$ is true, so the function is even.

For every $a,b\in A_f$, the sentence $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ is true(since $True \Rightarrow True$ is $True$) (and of course the contrapositive sentence is also true). So the function is injective.

Am I wrong somewhere? If not, why do so many people(even mathematicians) say that there can't be an even function that is injective even though there are many simple examples like the above?

Comment: Maybe they actually mean that an even function with at least two points in its domain.

Comment: So the function is $f:\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(0)=73$ (why $73$?). Anyway, any function $\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ is rather trivially both even and injective.

Comment: I think it's implied when that statement is made that the domain is the reals, which your examples don't satisfy.

Comment: @Bach Yes I agree that the statement is true for any function with at least 2 points. But generally false if I don't specify this.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown As for why 73, there is not any real reason, just that I like 73. You can google '73 sheldon best number' to see the reasons why(there are many). Yes the functions you described are all both even and injective. Thanks!

Comment: in the case when your domain has one point, it isn't very constructive to talk about injectivity or even-ness

Comment: @staedtlerr It is true that functions with domain of only one point have no real applications(none I can think of at least) but I am asking from a theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be such that there is some $a \in A$ with $-a \in A$ and $a \not = 0$. Then $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ cannot be both even and injective. But this is the most you can say.

(Of course, if you have an even function whose domain has a nonzero point in it, then the domain satisfies the above condition and so the function is not injective.)